# Javascript DateTime Being Changed by C# Web API Due to Timezone

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, datetime

I have an issue that i can't seem to figure out. I'm currently using AngularJS/Javascript to post a date to the Web API.

In AngularJS, i bind a variable to an input type="date" html control like so:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.searchRequest.DOB" />
```

I type in the date 10/30/1992 into the html control and in the AngularJS controller I have a console.log like so:

```
console.log(vm.searchRequest.DOB);
```

The console.log outputs

```
Fri Oct 30 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

When this date is posted the Web API and I step through to my values i see this:

[image]

I cannot figure out what is causing this conversion - is ther a simple, safe way i can prevent this conversoin from occurring so I have the correct date?

Comment: Could you place display format attribute `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` on DOB property, and see any different?

Comment: Why would you want to use type="date" ?! It has so many flaws like timezone, compatibility, It's not even supported for firefox and IE11. You can just have type="text" and use momentjs to convert it into moment object which handles all the date related manipulation, formatting, etc. And it's very fast so surely will not cause any performance issues. And practically you should only send & get timestamp from your service/DB converting it into readable local timezone date should be handled at front-end

Comment: I wasn't aware of its flaws. This app is also ran in a controlled environment where i know everyone is using Chrome. I suppose i will look into simply converting it to text and seeing if that fixes things.

Comment: I suggest you use the browser's developer tools to see what the actual request to WebAPI looks like. Dates have no standard representation in JSON, so either side might be doing a funky conversion.

Comment: What timezone does the C# DateTime object think it is? It may be the right TIME just wrong timezone (which is fine)

Comment: @99823 are you by any chance using the .toString() method in your javascript code? If so, that may be causing the timezone specific date conversion.